# open new console/lxterminal window using bash - Raspbian Jessie Lite

Tags: bash, terminal, debian, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

**EDIT**

> Raspbian Jessie Lite does not open to LXTerminal gui - it's just a
>   console window - so unless there's a way to open a new "console"
>   window it looks like I need to install lxterminal

I want to run a bash script and at the end just `open a new command in another LXTerminal window` and let it run while I still have command line in my login window, when the bash script ends.

I'm running Raspbian Jessie Lite on a Pi 3

I'm new in the Linux world - so I've tried typing in lxterm, lxterminal,  LXTerminal from command line, obviously misunderstanding what is required.

I've also tried running the command in the background using "&" but it seems to need terminal for output, as it fails and I can't see why. It runs fine by itself, but dumps a lot of continuous text to the terminal.

Is it possible to open a new terminal window in Jessie Lite - if I can do that I can figure out how to pass the command to it when I start it up

Hoping it's an easy solution that I'm missing because of my newness to the Linux world

**EDIT**

> Note that I'm willing to download any utilities or other terminals if
>   that makes it possible

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `bash` built-in [`lxterminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html) programatically for this.

```
lxterminal\
    --title="MyScriptWindow" \
    -e "bash -c ./somescript.sh;bash"\
```

`bash` is triggered manually at the end to prevent the terminal from closing, after the command or the script completes.

Comment: [\[ This \]](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39933) says `lite distribution is just a Minimal image based on Debian Jessie without the X-server and its components installed`. The op might have installed X-Server though. in that case he shouldn't have mentioned `Jessie Lite` in title..

Comment: And the default terminal in Raspbian  [\[ is \]](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/terminal/) is `LXterminal`.

Comment: @sjsam: I guess, `lxterminal` supports the same options too, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html

Comment: The point anyway is LXterminal is a GUI, and NOT a console application, which is not available in Jessie Lite by default.

Comment: Never installed X-Server. From what I've read, it boots to lxterminal command line.If that's not true, what is the command line program that I'm sitting at? It doesn't look like a GUI - and feels like a console app - but I know very little about Linux.

Comment: @Inian - so will that only be available from inside a bash script? As I said in my question, typing lxterminal from $ says command not found

Comment: @sjsam - this url lists all packages installed on jessie lite and includes lxterminal http://n8henrie.com/2015/12/default-packages-on-raspbian-jessie-jessie-lite-and-wheezy/

Comment: Jessie Lite does NOT open to a gui terminal - it's basically a console screen. So I guess I need to install lxterminal to do what I want? Or is it possible to open another "console" window?